# Why am I getting the OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' exception?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to update an MS Access database using a parameterized OLEDB command. Every time I try though, it gives me this exception: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'`

Running the query from within Access works fine, but from my WinForm program it fails for some reason.

```
string x =
                $"UPDATE CharMain " +
                $"SET CharMain.SpeciesAndStock = @SpeciesStock, " +
                    $"CharMain.Mig = @Might, " +
                    $"CharMain.Con = @Con, " +
                    $"CharMain.Dex = @Dex, " +
                    $"CharMain.Per = @Per, " +
                    $"CharMain.[Int] = @Int, " +
                    $"CharMain.Res = @Res, " +
                    $"CharMain.[Size] = @Size, " +
                    $"CharMain.Stride = @Stride " +
                $"WHERE CharMain.[ID] = @ID;";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(x, Flowsheet_101___Culture.conn);
            OleDbParameter[] param = new OleDbParameter[10];
            param[0] = new OleDbParameter("@SpeciesStock", speciesStock);
            param[1] = new OleDbParameter("@Might", array["Might"]);
            param[2] = new OleDbParameter("@Con", array["Constitution"]);
            param[3] = new OleDbParameter("@Dex", array["Dexterity"]);
            param[4] = new OleDbParameter("@Per", array["Perception"]);
            param[5] = new OleDbParameter("@Int", array["Intelligence"]);
            param[6] = new OleDbParameter("@Res", array["Resolve"]);
            param[7] = new OleDbParameter("@Size", size);
            param[8] = new OleDbParameter("@Stride", stride);
            param[9] = new OleDbParameter("@ID", Flowsheet_101___Culture.thisCharID);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[0]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[1]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[2]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[3]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[4]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[5]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[6]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[7]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[8]);
            command.Parameters.Add(param[9]);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: From the documentation "The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: @Ralf I did see that in some other answers. I thought that since my parameters are in the same order as in the query it shouldn't matter, should it?

Answer (score -1):

I realised that I've been trying to insert into columns that appear on another table. I thought this whole time the error was talking about missing parameters, but it turns out I was just referencing columns which weren't there.